# Does Spellthief's Edge effect Heimerdinger's Turrets?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I start off with Spellthief's Edge will my Turets be effected? like if they hit a champion then I get gold from it?

I've been thinking about trying it on Heimerdinger, but wanted to double check if it would work first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested it and I came to the following result:

The basic attacks of small turrets will not trigger the passive. However the beam (special attack of the turrets) will trigger it and give the right amount of gold.

For the Big turret you can place with the ultimate, even basic attacks will trigger the passive and not only the beam.

Comment: Also, Zyra's plants will trigger the passive, just fyi.